# In my React application, mobx @action is not firing - mobx , mobx-react-lite

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react, mobx-react-lite

I am using `mobx` & `mobx-react-lite` for first time and I can see the `@action` is not firing any events.

Please find the [Code SandBox url here](https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-cdn-jig1k)

My intention is when I click on button, the name CHAN should change to XIAN. But it's not happening. Can you please let me know where I made wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `makeObservable` in the myStore constructor.

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-tdd-4kony?file=/src/Store/store.tsx)

[Documentation](https://mobx.js.org/enabling-decorators.html#enabling-decorators-)

```
import { observable, action, makeObservable } from "mobx";

export class myStore {
  @observable name: string = "CHAN";

  constructor() {
    makeObservable(this)
  }

  @action
  setName(newName: string) {
    this.name = newName;
  }
}
```

Comment: It didn't allow me to accept the answer for first few minutes. I have accepted it now. Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: I just have one more basic question. Is wrapping the `observer` once around the code in `app.tsx` is enough for the entire app to make it reactive?

Comment: No, you should wrap each component which should be reactive with `observer`. This is because `observer` only subscribes to consumed properties in its own render function. E.g. if you pass the complete store to a child component, it won't re-rerender because the store itself won't change.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Christiaan answer, you can also use `makeAutoObservable` and drop decorators altogether!

```
import { observable, action, makeAutoObservable } from "mobx";

export class myStore {
  name: string = "CHAN";

  constructor() {
    makeAutoObservable(this)
  }

  setName(newName: string) {
    this.name = newName;
  }
}
```

More info: https://mobx.js.org/react-integration.html

Comment: I will make a note of it. Thank you so much.

Comment: I just have one more basic question. Is wrapping the observer once around the code in app.tsx is enough for the entire app to make it reactive?

Comment: Nope, you need to wrap every component which uses any observable or computed value. It's easier to jut wrap everything, honestly.